# Any Rails helper for has_many_and_belongs_to dependent form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any helper in Rails4 which allows quickly build forms for model with has_many_and_belongs_to? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I solved this problem by means of perfect gem called `nested_form` https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form